# Progress bar with parfor and nohup

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, nohup, parfor

I'd like to monitor the progress of a script making use of *`parfor`*. Unfortunately, since it requires a large amount of computational power and time, I have to launch it on a remote multiprocessor computer, using *`nohup`*.

As a first attempt, I used *`fprintf`* in order to have an output from each of the parallel instances, i.e.

```
parfor i = 1:N
    fprintf('Computing instance %i out of %i\n', i, N)
    % Other code
end
```

and counting the occurences of the word "instance" in the `nohup` output file, using *`grep`*. However, since **`N`** is in the order of `~ 1E8 ~` some hundreds of millions, the output file become huge and so I'd like to avoid it.

Then, I start trying some `parfor` progress bar I can find on the Internet. However, most of them are made to use a graphic output and the few other ones have some drawbacks if used together with `nohup` (e.g. in the output file I found every single update of the progress bar, so again the output file will be huge).

How can I effectively monitor a `parfor`, while using `nohup`?

Comment: If `N` is in the order of some hundreds of millions, you may want to consider having an outer `for` loop and monitoring the progress of that loop.

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *"How can I effectively monitor a `parfor`, while using `nohup`?"*

I would prefer to use ZeroMQ / JeroMQ-port and explicitly signal from inside the `parfor` any actual (relevant) progress.

```
import org.zeromq.ZMQ;

aCtx = zmq.Ctx();
ADDR = 'tcp://127.0.0.1:75757';

parfor i = 1:N
     fprintf( 'Computing instance %i out of %i\n', i, N );
     %---------------------------------------------------------------------
                                     aSocket = aCtx.createSocket( ZMQ.PUB );    
                                     aSocket.connect( ADDR );
                                     aMessage = zmq.Msg( 9 );
                                     aMessage.put( unicode2native( 'SIG:START' ) );
                                     aSocket.send( aMessage, 1 );
     %---------------------------------------------------------------------
     % Other code
     %---------------------------------------------------------------------
                                     aMessage = zmq.Msg( 7 );
                                     aMessage.put( unicode2native( 'SIG:END' ) );
                                     aSocket.send( aMessage, 1 );
                                     aSocket.close();
     %---------------------------------------------------------------------

end
```

For this you will need a **`SUB`**-scriber side, collecting all signal-messages, obviously `.bind()` and ready on the above defined `ADDR:PORT` address, having GUI or being headless, all depends on your preferred language & monitor needs.

### How ?

Re-use Will Grant's installation [advice](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/269061-how-do-i-integrate-zeromq-library-with-matlab-i-want-my-matlab-program-to-be-a-subscriber-of-zeromq) and links referred by him.